# Woocomerce adding items to cart from a share cart url?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I think I need help in here, Im not really sure if I need to set the session manually or it will set automatically while adding items to woocommerce cart, lets consider the following:

```
if(is_array($args_n)){
    foreach($args_n as $item){
        $is_product_in_cart = false;
        if(sizeof( WC()->instance()->cart->get_cart() > 0)){
            foreach(WC()->instance()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_items_key => $cart_items_values){
                $products = $cart_items_values['data'];
                if($products->id == $item){
                    $is_product_in_cart = true;
                }
            }
            if(!$is_product_in_cart){
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $item );
            }
        }else{
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $item );
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I do the following:

```
var_dump(sizeof(WC()->instance()->cart->get_cart()));
```

At the beginning of the call I get `0` after the code has been executed I get the right value == `3`(for this example);

The arguments being passed is just a simple array with products id's fx:

```
$args_n = array(
        2080,
        720,
        835,
    );
```

This array is created with a parse url and implode, nothing from the other world

The issue is, even tho all looks good since I get the right number from the cart size when I do go to the cart page, it still empty!. Any ideas or hints?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Debug info:

Adding a simple eco to the the id being pass:

```
echo "---> {$item} \n";
```

Before being redirect, I run this:

```
$cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($cart_items as $i => $x){
    $p = $x['data']->post;
    echo " in cart ---> {$p->ID} \n";
}
```

The result is:

```
int(0) ---> 2080 ---> 720 ---> 835 int(3) in cart ---> 2080 in cart ---> 720 in cart ---> 835
```

So all items are in the cart! but still no there when the redirect is done, or just navigation away from that landing page.

**EDIT:**

When checking woocommerce `WC()->session` I get the result saying the session is alive with the items added to the cart..

```
object(WC_Session_Handler)#173 (7) {
  ["_cookie":"WC_Session_Handler":private]=>
  string(55) "wp_woocommerce_session_77f1e25389fdbfe3480cc6593d3838b0"
  ["_session_expiring":"WC_Session_Handler":private]=>
  int(1440319051)
  ["_session_expiration":"WC_Session_Handler":private]=>
  int(1440322651)
  ["_has_cookie":"WC_Session_Handler":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_customer_id":protected]=>
  string(32) "57cd99b8855e872adad62440a6c2fbe0"
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(20) {
    ["cart"]=>
    string(904) "a:3:{s:32:"54ff9e9e3a2ec0300d4ce11261f5169f";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:2080;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:1;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:1;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}s:32:"5f2c22cb4a5380af7ca75622a6426917";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:720;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:1;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:1;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}s:32:"4d5b995358e7798bc7e9d9db83c612a5";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:835;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:1;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:1;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}"
    ["applied_coupons"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
    ["coupon_discount_amounts"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
    ["coupon_discount_tax_amounts"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
    ["removed_cart_contents"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
    ["cart_contents_total"]=>
    float(3)
    ["cart_contents_weight"]=>
    int(0)
    ["cart_contents_count"]=>
    int(3)
    ["total"]=>
    int(0)
    ["subtotal"]=>
    int(3)
    ["subtotal_ex_tax"]=>
    int(3)
    ["tax_total"]=>
    int(0)
    ["taxes"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
    ["shipping_taxes"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
    ["discount_cart"]=>
    int(0)
    ["discount_cart_tax"]=>
    int(0)
    ["shipping_total"]=>
    int(0)
    ["shipping_tax_total"]=>
    int(0)
    ["fee_total"]=>
    int(0)
    ["fees"]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
  }
  ["_dirty":protected]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

**EDIT**

If there is item at the cart already, and the function is triggered it will work as it is suppose to, so I guess is a session issue

Comment: On which hook are you running the `if` condition code?

Comment: @Anand is running inside a shorcut that is place inside a dummy page. to handle the request once wp is loaded so fx-> `example.com/duumy/?function=121,212,3321`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spun up a new WooCommerce and tried out your code - I was not able to replicate the issue. I think it's possible that this is a load-order issue. WooCommerce creates a session and a cart for every visitor, so I don't think it's a matter of the cart not being "primed" with an existing session or anything like that. Often I find that you need to find the right hook, especially when dealing with the WooCommerce cart. WooCommerce actually keeps cart information in three spots: The cart object instance, the user's session, and a persistent cart in the database. Getting any updates to work in harmony with the dance that WooCommerce is doing between those can be tricky. I have found that the most reliable time to add items to a cart before a full page load is in the 'template_redirect' hook. It's after all session data and queries have run, but before the page is constructed. It's good for manipulating things just before you want to display them to the user.

Here's how I implemented your code, and it works on empty carts:

```
add_action('template_redirect','custom_add_to_cart', 1000);
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    $args_n = array(10, 11); // I just made an array with dummy product ids

    if(is_array($args_n)){
        foreach($args_n as $item){
            $is_product_in_cart = false;
            if(sizeof( WC()->instance()->cart->get_cart() > 0)){
                foreach(WC()->instance()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_items_key => $cart_items_values){
                    $products = $cart_items_values['data'];
                    if($products->id == $item){
                        $is_product_in_cart = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!$is_product_in_cart){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $item );
                }
            }else{
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $item );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try that and let us know if it works more reliably!

Comment: I did try `template_redirect ` but I need to pass and arg since $args_n is a dynamic variable that gets its value from the url when the page loads and I can't pass arguments with that hook

Comment: Why not just move your $_GET['function'] and explode() to the custom_add_to_cart() function? This worked when I tested it: http://pastebin.com/WT8xLf4X

Comment: Thanks mate, I dont know why I didnt think in that before I just added some checks to make sure I dont add things when is not needed :)

Comment: I think that's half the usefulness of this site - you get other people noticing things that you never would. I'll often spend hours on a problem, then ask a friend who sees the answer in seconds. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to an article by Mike Jolley [here](http://mikejolley.com/2013/12/20/problems-with-cart-sessions-and-woocommerce/):

" **Problems with caching**

Page cache added by plugins, and by hosts such as WPEngine, can break sessions. Well, not break, just show a page which is cached and as a result doesn’t reflect the current users cart.

When a cart session is present some data needs to be un-cached, as do some pages such as cart, checkout and account." -Mike Jolley

I think this is a strong possibility of what is going wrong, as the normal ways of starting sessions have been waived for WP_SESSION in the WC platform. Try calling your hosting provider to see if varnish caching is enabled on your server and see if they can provide a way around it.